# how to use the vb code for the entire column based on the condition

Tags: vba, excel

I want to disable one cell in excel based on the condition of the previous cell, for example, if A3="xyz" then B3= disable, and I have achieved this by the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target <> Range("A3") Then Exit Sub

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect

    If Range("A3").Value = "CNS" Then
        Range("B3").Locked = True
    End If

    If Range("A3").Value = "APL" Then
        Range("B3").Locked = False
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Protect

End Sub
```

Now I want to use this code for the entire A column. If I enter `A4` or `A5`, then the corresponding `B4` or `B5` should become disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work just fine :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect
        Select Case UCase(Target.Value)
            Case Is = "CNS"
                Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = True
            Case Is = "APL"
                Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = False
            Case Else
                MsgBox "Value not covered by the program", vbInformation + vbOKOnly
        End Select
        ActiveSheet.Protect
    Else
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You might have a problem with that trying to run on top of itself. Fix with `Application.EnableEvents = False` and restore before leaving.

Comment: @Jeeped : Thx for input, Indeed I should have included that good practice, but the initial code wouldn't have effect as the modified cell is out of the scope of the code actually doing something, but I'll include it anyway!

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution, it is working well

Comment: this code is wrking well for cell A2 and B2, but how to change the columns???? like in D2 and F2??

Comment: Change `1` in `Me.Columns(1)` to `4` for column D, and adjust `Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked` to select the good column, here for F, you need to move 2 columns on the right so it'll be `Target.Offset(0, 2).Locked`! ;)

Comment: actually it is always going to the else part, means whenever i am going to the  D column for choosing either "apl" or "cns", this" value not covered by the program" message is coming.
pls help

Comment: @nina : Ok, try the edit, that should be ok (it was most probably just the difference of capitalization). If it didn't fix it, just copy the value from the cell and paste it in the code!